# How-to make file have different color when doing ls?

Tags: bash, colors, color-management

When I execute command

> ls

it displays files and folders. folders are typed in light blue. I would like to have xml files types in pink color.

How to do it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can edit `~/.dircolors`, if it doesn't exist you can create it with:

```
dircolors -p > ~/.dir_colors
```

As the [example here](http://news-posts.aplawrence.com/345.html) shows, you can have this in your .bashrc:

```
eval `dircolors ~/.dir_colors`
alias ls="ls --color=auto"
```

Answer (score 1):

one doesn't need to add anything to the  /home/yourusername/.bashrc file
since it already contains the nessecary entries

just search for --color and uncomment them so they are active!